# JAX-WS Outside of App Server

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm trying to learn about JAX-WS, specifically using WSDLs in Java.

I want to use a small footprint WebServer/Tool (Not a full blown App Server).  Any suggestions on where to start?  Specific tools/technologies/tutorials/websites would be appreciated.

Most of what I have found has dealt with App Servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most lightweight solution would be to just [use the server provided by JDK6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) itself:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public static void main(String[] args) {

      Endpoint.publish(
         "http://localhost:8080/WebServiceExample/circlefunctions",
         new CircleFunctions());

}
```

At least for testing that could be useful.

Comment: Is this still available in Java 8?

Comment: @dubdubdubdot: I would assume so. They usually don't take away things. Note that it does not use any `com.sun` or `com.oracle` internal packages but that this is part of the official `javax.xml.ws` API.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the WSDL then you can learn the client programming model without the need for AppServier. All you need is the [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) tool. It can act as a [MockServer](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/mocking-soap-services.html) for your WSDL.